# Hangfire Postgres - re-enque job when server dies

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, hangfire

In our project we are using dotnet core, Hangfire and Postgres. We have some medium duration jobs (~10-15min) that we schedule on Hangfire.

The issue is that from time to time the Hangfire server that is processing a job might die and a new one is started. Obviously the job that was being processed needs re-enquing as it will never be completed otherwise. Hangfire seems to know the server that was executing the job is dead - nonetheless other servers won't pick up the job automatically and we need to re-enque it, which is not great.

Is there a way to get Hangfire to re-enque processing jobs when the server that was executing them is dead?

Thanks a lot!
Donato

Comment: Normally the jobs are queued and once they are picked up by a worker, other workers will not touch it (whether it is running or orphaned). In my implementation, it seemed unreasonable to spend time on infrastructure to restart a job which would keep track of running jobs (DB models) and re-enqueue if status is failed / unavailable.

Comment: If still available, you may try the obsolete, but useful, InvisibilityTimeout setting. See  https://github.com/arnoldasgudas/Hangfire.MySqlStorage/issues/20#issuecomment-291917636